# Weak solutions for elliptic equations

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, regularity-theory-of-pdes

i have two questions about the study of weak solutions for elliptic equations?

[image]

- Why study these equations in divergent form?
- Why the minus sign in the principal part?

Thanks very much

Comment: The short answer is: "keep on reading, you'll find out yourself". Anyway, the minus is just a convention, while the divergence form is better suited to the integration by parts that is surely coming a couple of lines below that excerpt.

Comment: Indeed, the divergence form helps the integration by parts. If $a_{ij}$ is $C^{1}$, then the divergence and non-divergence form is equivalent. What is the convention you speak?

Comment: The minus sign makes it so that if $A$ is a positive definite matrix then the bilinear form corresponding to $u \mapsto \nabla \cdot (a \nabla u)$ is positive definite. Without the minus sign it is negative definite, which is fine but creates more minus signs further down the line.

Comment: Also use the search function: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772588/what-is-precisely-the-definition-of-elliptic-partial-differential-equation/1772653#1772653