# The sign of elliptic operator (divergence form)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

The elliptic operator (in divergence form) in (Evans, and many texts) is defined as
$$Lu=-D_j(a^{ij}D_i u)+b^i D_i u+cu$$
$D_i u$ denotes $u_{x_i}$,assuming the summation convention is understood.

While in some other texts, there is a plus sign instead of a minus in front of the leading term, i.e. 
$$Lu=D_j(a^{ij}D_i u)+b^i D_i u+cu.$$

Obviously among all authors, the sign plays no role. But why? Could anyone reconcile the difference of the two versions? The sign does not matter, why?

Comment: It's due to integration by parts on the first term. More precisely, you want to have a plus sign after integration by parts, so people often put a minus sign in front of the term term.

Comment: could you wrue explicitly what you mean?

Comment: Usually the sign depends on the Dirichlet problem wich you consider. For example, here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772588/what-is-precisely-the-definition-of-elliptic-partial-differential-equation/1772653#1772653  the reference is a book of A. Bressan

Answer (score 2):

Just as what you did on your previous question on MSE, to obtain a weak formulation of the problem, we multiply the $Lu$ by test functions $v\in H_0^1$ and integrate by parts. Doing so for the first term,
\begin{align*}
\int_\Omega -D_j(a^{ij}D_iu)v & = \int_{\partial\Omega} -(a^{ij}D_iu)v - \int_{\Omega} -a^{ij}D_iuD_jv\\
& = \int_\Omega a^{ij}D_iuD_jv \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where the first term vanishes due to $v\in H_0^1$. You should be able to see that if we have $D_j(a^{ij}D_iu)$ instead, equation (1) will have an extra minus sign instead. This is what I meant by people wanting to have a plus sign after integrating by parts.

Comment: Note that the other two terms doesn't require integration by parts.

Comment: No. I am comparing only for the divergence form, in Evans, the leading term is negative, while in GT, the leading term positive, see page 45. He has $D_j(a^{ij}D_i u)$

Comment: I am aware of that. The point is, sign doesn't matter because it's a matter of presentation here. You would want a bilinear form associated to $L$ to be $B(u,v) = \int_\Omega a^{ij}D_iuD_jv + b^i(D_iu)v + cuv$, instead of $\tilde{B}(u,v) = \int_\Omega -a^{ij}D_iuD_jv + b^i(D_iu)v + cuv$, which is what you would get if you assign a positive sign to the leading term.